# Will this people enter paradise?

Tags: hadith, jannah, jahannam

We know Syed-ul-istigfar is the best dua for forgiveness and prophet PBUH also said if we someone reads it will full believe he will enter paradise if he dies that day. My question is if someone doesn't respect parents, sever ties of kinship, hot tempered and have pride will he enter paradise because these categories of people will enter hellfire?
Please help in this regard.
Jazakallah Khairan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course. All Muslim will enter heaven/paradise eventually. What matters here is **how long is the waiting and when**. Qur’an and Sunnah and ijma ’generation of salaf of this ummah has shown that a person who still has faith in his heart despite the weight of an atom, will not remain in hell. If he goes to hell for his sins, he will stay there according to God's will, then he will be released and go to heaven.

In the Qur’an *(Surah al-A’raf, verse 156)*, Allah states that Allah’s mercy overcomes all things. The question of heaven and hell, it is a matter of God's provision. However, our job as human beings is to call for good. This matter is emphasized by the Qur'an itself, that the task of Muhammad saw is to convey, while the determination of guidance is Allah's.